# CASE WHEN expressions with NULL values (Hiveql)

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
      rv.country
    , coalesce(rv.client_id, client_id2) as AccountID
    , coalesce(c.name, rv.client_id2)  as AccountName
    , rv.prod_type as ProdType,
    CASE WHEN cs.prod_type IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE cs.prod_type END as ProdType1,
    ROUND(-SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(current_date(), rv.date_time) < 90 THEN rv.sold_prods END)) as Last3Months,
    ROUND(-SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(current_date(), rv.date_time) < 180 THEN rv.sold_prods END)) as Last6Months,
    ROUND(-SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(current_date(), rv.date_time) < 360 THEN rv.sold_prods END)) as Last12Months
FROM
    commercial.sold_products rv
LEFT JOIN commercial.customer c
ON c.client_id2 = rv.client_id

LEFT JOIN 
    commercial.customer_description cs
ON
    cs.clientid = c.client_id2
    
WHERE rv.country NOT IN ('US', 'JP')
AND cs.prod_type = rv.prod_type
GROUP BY
      rv.country
    , rv.client_id
    , rv.client_id2
    , cs.prod_type
    , c.name
    , rv.prod_type;
```

Expected output: (With current # amount of values, of course)
[image]

I have 3 CASE WHEN statements that are supposed to represent the # of sold products in the last 3, 6 and 12 months. However, some clients appear with NULL values even though I am aware we sold them products 22 days ago (example).

I'm not sure what's wrong with this query, so if you notice something please let me know!

**Also!** Ignore the columns/tables names, I changed them because of company privacy issues. Thank you :)

Comment: `IS NULL` will match null values - combine this with `OR`

Comment: `AND cs.prod_type = rv.prod_type` is a join condition. Move to ON, and you'll get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: BTW, those are `case` _expressions_.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause `cs.prod_type = rv.prod_type` will filter out `NULL` values in either of those fields. However in your `SELECT` you have `CASE WHEN cs.prod_type IS NULL` so I'm guessing you don't really want to do that. Admittedly this is probably not your main issue. Would be good to have some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Is `coalesce(c.name, rv.client_id2)` expected to return a name (character) or an id (integer)?

Comment: @SteveLovell Please see the update.

Comment: @jarlh regarding your questions, where exactly should I move the cs.prod_type = rv.prod_type condition? The LEFT JOINs I'm using connect rv table to c table and c table to cs table.

In regards to COALESCE, it returns the name (string), but if the name is empty it returns the id (integer).

Comment: I'd expect an exception for a COALESCE with non-matching types, but perhaps Hive has other rules?

Comment: The `cs.prod_type = rv.prod_type` line should appear (prefaced with `AND`) after your `cs.clientid = c.client_id2` line.

Comment: Move it to the second ON. (cs columns aren't in scope before the cs table has been specified.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've changed the query :)

Comment: The sum columns still don't work properly. Any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't your GROUP BY columns match the non-aggregated columns in your SELECT?

Comment: Do you have a separate query which retrieves the data you are expecting to feature here? i.e. can you give us the "bare" source data (suitably changed for privacy).

Comment: This condition in the WHERE `AND cs.prod_type = rv.prod_type` turns your LEFT JOINS to INNER. because it does not allow nulls both in cs and c tables. INNER JOIN can reduce the dataset in rv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query like this:

```
SELECT
      rv.country
    , coalesce(rv.client_id, client_id2) as AccountID
    , coalesce(c.name, rv.client_id2)  as AccountName
    , rv.prod_type as ProdType,
    CASE WHEN cs.prod_type IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE cs.prod_type END as ProdType1,
    ROUND(-SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(current_date(), rv.date_time) < 90 THEN rv.sold_prods END)) as Last3Months,
    ROUND(-SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(current_date(), rv.date_time) < 180 THEN rv.sold_prods END)) as Last6Months,
    ROUND(-SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(current_date(), rv.date_time) < 360 THEN rv.sold_prods END)) as Last12Months
FROM
    commercial.sold_products rv
LEFT JOIN commercial.customer c
ON c.client_id2 = rv.client_id

LEFT JOIN 
    commercial.customer_description cs
ON
    cs.clientid = c.client_id2 AND cs.prod_type = rv.prod_type
    
WHERE rv.country NOT IN ('US', 'JP')
GROUP BY
      rv.country
    , coalesce(rv.client_id, rv.client_id2) 
    , rv.client_id2
    , cs.prod_type
    , coalesce(c.name, rv.client_id2)
    , rv.prod_type;
```

If not correct you can share some sample data to check and I think you should focus on your group by items.